# TableView Row unable to Select

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I defined my own controller with no nib file like this:

```
@interface EngineViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> {
    EngineViewProperties* viewProp;
    UIImageView *imgView; // image view of selected engine
    NSUInteger selectedIndex;
    UITableView *menu;
}

@property (nonatomic,retain) EngineViewProperties* viewProp;

- (EngineViewController *) initWithEngineViewProperties: (EngineViewProperties *) _viewProp;

- (void) dropdownMenu: (id) sender;
```

I created my view in loadView,with three subviews. The subview arrowBtn is helped to popup a list of search engines.

```
- (void)loadView {
    // ...
    UIButton *arrowBtn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
    [arrowBtn setImage:viewProp.arrowImg forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [arrowBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(dropdownMenu:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [self.view addSubview:imgView];
    [self.view addSubview:label];
    [self.view addSubview:arrowBtn];
    // ...
}
```

I create a table listing search engines in the selector dropdownMenu:

```
- (void) dropdownMenu: (id) sender {
    UIButton *arrowBtn = (UIButton *)sender;
    // ...
    menu = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:rect style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    menu.delegate = self;
    menu.dataSource = self;
    menu.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    menu.allowsSelection = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:menu];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:menu];
    [menu release];
}
```

And I implemented

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

as usual.
But the result is that the menu popup happily,but I can do nothing with the cells.I clicked the cells,but no response.Those methods like "didSelectRowAtIndexPath" can not be called.
Sorry to paste up so much codes one time.But I really need help.I don't know what is the problem.Please forgive me for my poor English and low development skill in Iphone.And thanks a lot if you give me a little suggestions.

//Added-------------------------

"numberOfRowsInSection" is simple:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [viewProp.txtArray count];
}
```

and another method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *MenuItems = @"MenuItems";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MenuItems];
    if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier: MenuItems] autorelease];
    }
    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];

    cell.imageView.image = [viewProp.imgArray objectAtIndex:row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [viewProp.txtArray objectAtIndex:row];
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone; // Blue style tried,helpless too
    if (row == selectedIndex) {
            cell.selected = YES;
    }
    cell.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    return cell;
}
```

// Added

Strangely,when the menu firstly poped up,the default selected cell was highlighted correctly,but very quickly the highlighting disappeard.

Comment: Have you added delegate to view controller.. i.e. <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>.. add this next to the UIViewController in .h file

Comment: cellForRowAtIndexPath: code please

Comment: Check if you have not registered `UITapGestureRecognizer` in `self.view` which may conflict with it (I had same problem issue and I moved tap registration to tableview.tableheaderview to resolve the issue).

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have implemented this

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                   initWithTarget:self
                                   action:@selector(dismissKeyboard)];

[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];
```

The `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`  will not called if this is present. One way to workaround this is set `[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];` towards your targeted view only such as `[self.svContent addGestureRecognizer:tap];`.

Alternatively, check which view is touched.

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
{
    if ((touch.view == YourTable)) 
    {
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;
```

in your

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

for your cell.

remove

```
cell.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

code from your file.

Comment: I don't think the key problem is the cell.Because when the menu firstly poped up,the default selected cell was highlighted,but quickly the highlighting disappeard.

Comment: i think then this might should not the be the problem if you didnt use `UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone`. try clean build and paste some of your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` code.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving `cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue` in your table View data source. Also check if the `userInteraction` is enabled for the table view and the cells.

Comment: I have set cell.selectionStyle,and I enabled userInteraction.But useless.

Answer (score 0):

Are you showing any data in the table have you implemented

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
```

in you viewController??

Seems that you are setting the delgate property correctly, also you added the protocols  to the same ViewController. So the problem can be either there is no data in the tableView for selection, or there is some View on top of tableView which is blocking you interaction with the tableView.

Comment: I implemented "numberOfSectionsInTableView",and the menu poped up correctly.Though the self.view is the leftview of a UITextField view,I kept enough space under the UITextField view for testing.I don't know whether there is any inner mechanism blocking my subview.I am a new comer in the iphone world.

Comment: the self.view is the leftview?? of a UITextField view? what does this mean? try removing all the views from your view, load only tableView with some data, and then try out. If it works, then definitely some problem with your other views. Btw are you adding the table on self.view or some other view?